# when switch is "ON", code check specific condition continuously until the user make switch "OFF" (in flutter)

Tags: flutter

When the user make switch "ON" , some specific condition will be checking under the while loop. But the user make switch "OFF" before hitting condition then the switch should be "OFF".

But the problem is that code is unable to make switch "OFF" when the user make switch "OFF" i.e. it means code is unable to exit from while loop when the user clicked on switch to make it "OFF".

I am expecting from the code:

- When the user clicked on switch to make Switch "ON" then the code will go under the "While loop" to check some specific condition until the hitting condition.
- Before hitting condition if the user clicked again on switch to make Switch "OFF" then the code "break" the "while" loop and make Switch "OFF"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYzZv.png)

Comment: Where are you changing the value of position or making switch off?

Comment: decrement of i (variable) by 1 i.e. (i--)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20153035)